# How can I shuffle a large amount of websites quickly?

Tags: python, shuffle

I have more than 15200 links to websites which I need to shuffle.

If I had a small number of websites, I can enter them manually into python and use the following code to shuffle them:

```
from random import shuffle
x = ['website_1', 'website_2', 'website_3', 'website_4', 'website_5']
shuffle(x)
```

But entering more than 15200 links manually into a list is extremely time consuming because I would have to put quotation marks on them individually.

At the moment, I have the links in the following form:

```
website_1
website_2
website_3
.
.
.
website_15270
```

Is there a way I can enter the the website in the format shown above and have them shuffled and returned in the same format?

Comment: Are the links saved in a file or where are the links availabale?

Comment: The links are saved in a Notepad file.

Comment: You should probably adjust the title of this case. Your problem isn't shuffling, it's reading data from a file.

Answer (score 1):

Since the links are stored in a file:

```
from random import shuffle
with open(file) as f:
    links = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
shuffle(links)
```

Comment: If you are going to produce a list of lines without line separators, use `links = f.read().splitlines()`.

Answer (score 1):

You read your file and remove the newlines from each link..

```
import random

links = [link.rstrip("\n") for link in open("yourFileName").readlines()]
random.shuffle(links)
```

Comment: Where should the text file be saved?

Comment: insted of .replace maybe .rstrip?

Comment: in the same directory as your .py file is saved or type in an absolute path of the path e.g. in linux /home/username/directory1/links.txt

Comment: @Vizjerei actually in this case it doesn't matter, but you're right i think it's safer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can:

1. Create an array with values from 1 to #ofSites
2. Shuffle this array (I think is faster)
3. Create a list of site using this [How do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array)
4. Use the shuffled array as index for retrieve the sites from the list.